# Return all strings that 'starts with' in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, startswith

I created a dataframe from text files (very irregular from each other). I created a boolean array of all the strings that start with 'T-', using below 'masking'.

```
mask = np.column_stack([amadeus[col].str.startswith(r'T-', na=False) for col in amadeus])
```

Below you may see the dataframe (left) and the boolean matches of my 'masking'.

[image]

I have been trying to manage the irregularity of the files with dicts, etc. with no success.

What I really need is to use this masking to 'pull' the actual contents of the cells marked as 'True' into a dataframe. Something like:

[image]

This is just and intermediate step to other transformations I need to do.
Editing it, because it was wrongly tagged as duplicate.

Comment: pasting your question title into google led me to the linked duplicate

Comment: I don't think so, the other answer refers to pd series and by column. I'm looking at the full df. But I still need to extract the actual content by the 'masking'.